# Plotting Pooled Effect Sizes instead of the massive article list I have

Tags: r, metafor

I am in the process of running my meta-analysis. I want to do a nested analysis since I have multiple rows of data from the same article. This is how it currently looks in my line of code.

```
# fit a multivariate random-effects model with two moderators
res <- rma.mv(LRR_shootbiomass, LRR_var_shootbiomass, mods = ~ Stress+ NEW_stress_level+AMFColonization, random = ~ 1 | ID/Group_ID, data = AnalysisTable)
```

My question is, I would plot a forest plot with one column being the Stress than the stress level and their effect sizes. Can I do that with my current ram.mv, or how would I get the correct manner to resolve this?

I tried running them via # Calculate pooled effect sizes for each moderator

```
pooled1 <- rma(yi = res$beta[1], vi = res$V[1], method = "FE")
pooled2 <- rma(yi = res$beta[2], vi = res$V[2], method = "FE")
```

but I don't think I am doing it correctly.